# Are character encoding issue causing my Perl output to look like gibberish?

Tags: perl, character-encoding, solaris

I'm running a Perl script (both with 5.8.4) on two different machines (one Solaris 5.10, the other OpenSolaris 5.11). The output of the two scripts differs in the following way:

Solaris 5.10

```
 $ perl myscript.pl

 is&#39; £ ä º &lt;ä ¼ sa ... ³ ä º žÃ ... ¬ å ¸ ç ¬ ¬ ä º ¤ § œâ is œâ ¡ä ¸ ‡ å ... æœ ¬ æœ ¬ å ¸ È, ¡ä »½ çš&quot; å ... ¬ å&#39;Š
```

OpenSolaris 5.11

```
 $ perl myscript.pl

 Board of directors about the companys second-largest shareholder of the notice by Chibengongsi shares
```

Basically, the chars on the Solaris box are messed up. The output of locale on both is identical.

```
OpenSolaris

$ perl -V

Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 4) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=solaris, osvers=2.11, archname=i86pc-solaris-64int
    uname='sunos localhost 5.11 i86pc i386 i86pc'
    config_args=''
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    usethreads=undef use5005threads=undef useithreads=undef usemultiplicity=undef
    useperlio=define d_sfio=undef uselargefiles=define usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define use64bitall=undef uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_TS_ERRNO',
    optimize='-xO3 -xspace -xildoff',
    cppflags=''
    ccversion='Sun WorkShop', gccversion='', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
    ivtype='long long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=4, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc', ldflags =''
    libpth=/lib /usr/lib /usr/ccs/lib
    libs=-lsocket -lnsl -ldl -lm -lc
    perllibs=-lsocket -lnsl -ldl -lm -lc
    libc=/lib/libc.so, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-R /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/CORE'
    cccdlflags='-KPIC', lddlflags='-G'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: USE_64_BIT_INT USE_LARGE_FILES
  Locally applied patches:
        22667 The optree builder was looping when constructing the ops ...
        22715 Upgrade to FileCache 1.04
        22733 Missing copyright in the README.
        22746 fix a coredump caused by rv2gv not fully converting a PV ...
        22755 Fix 29149 - another UTF8 cache bug hit by substr.
        22774 [perl #28938] split could leave an array without ...
        22775 [perl #29127] scalar delete of empty slice returned garbage
        22776 [perl #28986] perl -e "open m" crashes Perl
        22777 add test for change #22776 ("open m" crashes Perl)
        22778 add test for change #22746 ([perl #29102] Crash on assign ...
        22781 [perl #29340] Bizarre copy of ARRAY make sure a pad op's ...
        22796 [perl #29346] Double warning for int(undef) and abs(undef) ...
        22818 BOM-marked and (BOMless) UTF-16 scripts not working
        22823 [perl #29581] glob() misses a lot of matches
        22827 Smoke [5.9.2] 22818 FAIL(F) MSWin32 WinXP/.Net SP1 (x86/1 cpu)
        22830 [perl #29637] Thread creation time is hypersensitive
        22831 improve hashing algorithm for ptr tables in perl_clone: ...
        22839 [perl #29790] Optimization busted: '@a = "b", sort @a' ...
        22850 [PATCH] 'perl -v' fails if local_patches contains code snippets
        22852 TEST needs to ignore SCM files
        22886 Pod::Find should ignore SCM files and dirs
        22888 Remove redundant %SIG assignments from FileCache
        23006 [perl #30509] use encoding and "eq" cause memory leak
        23074 Segfault using HTML::Entities
        23106 Numeric comparison operators mustn't compare addresses of ...
        23320 [perl #30066] Memory leak in nested shared data structures ...
        23321 [perl #31459] Bug in read()
        27722 perlio.c breaks on Solaris/gcc when > 256 FDs are available
        SPRINTF0 - fixes for sprintf formatting issues - CVE-2005-3962
        6663288 Upgrade to CGI.pm 3.33
        REGEXP0 - fix for UTF-8 recoding in regexps - CVE-2007-5116
        6758953 Perl Sys::Syslog can log messages with wrong severity
  Built under solaris
  Compiled at Apr  8 2009 17:12:58
  @INC:
    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int
    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib
    /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/i86pc-solaris-64int
    /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4
    /usr/perl5/site_perl
    /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/i86pc-solaris-64int
    /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4
    /usr/perl5/vendor_perl
    .
```

Solaris

```
$perl -V

Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 4) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=solaris, osvers=2.10, archname=i86pc-solaris-64int
    uname='sunos localhost 5.10 i86pc i386 i86pc'
    config_args=''
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    usethreads=undef use5005threads=undef useithreads=undef usemultiplicity=undef
    useperlio=define d_sfio=undef uselargefiles=define usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define use64bitall=undef uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_TS_ERRNO',
    optimize='-xO3 -xspace -xildoff',
    cppflags=''
    ccversion='Sun WorkShop', gccversion='', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
    ivtype='long long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=4, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc', ldflags =''
    libpth=/lib /usr/lib /usr/ccs/lib
    libs=-lsocket -lnsl -ldl -lm -lc
    perllibs=-lsocket -lnsl -ldl -lm -lc
    libc=/lib/libc.so, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-R /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/CORE'
    cccdlflags='-KPIC', lddlflags='-G'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: USE_64_BIT_INT USE_LARGE_FILES
  Locally applied patches:
        22667 The optree builder was looping when constructing the ops ...
        22715 Upgrade to FileCache 1.04
        22733 Missing copyright in the README.
        22746 fix a coredump caused by rv2gv not fully converting a PV ...
        22755 Fix 29149 - another UTF8 cache bug hit by substr.
        22774 [perl #28938] split could leave an array without ...
        22775 [perl #29127] scalar delete of empty slice returned garbage
        22776 [perl #28986] perl -e "open m" crashes Perl
        22777 add test for change #22776 ("open m" crashes Perl)
        22778 add test for change #22746 ([perl #29102] Crash on assign ...
        22781 [perl #29340] Bizarre copy of ARRAY make sure a pad op's ...
        22796 [perl #29346] Double warning for int(undef) and abs(undef) ...
        22818 BOM-marked and (BOMless) UTF-16 scripts not working
        22823 [perl #29581] glob() misses a lot of matches
        22827 Smoke [5.9.2] 22818 FAIL(F) MSWin32 WinXP/.Net SP1 (x86/1 cpu)
        22830 [perl #29637] Thread creation time is hypersensitive
        22831 improve hashing algorithm for ptr tables in perl_clone: ...
        22839 [perl #29790] Optimization busted: '@a = "b", sort @a' ...
        22850 [PATCH] 'perl -v' fails if local_patches contains code snippets
        22852 TEST needs to ignore SCM files
        22886 Pod::Find should ignore SCM files and dirs
        22888 Remove redundant %SIG assignments from FileCache
        23006 [perl #30509] use encoding and "eq" cause memory leak
        23074 Segfault using HTML::Entities
        23106 Numeric comparison operators mustn't compare addresses of ...
        23320 [perl #30066] Memory leak in nested shared data structures ...
        23321 [perl #31459] Bug in read()
        27722 perlio.c breaks on Solaris/gcc when > 256 FDs are available
        SPRINTF0 - fixes for sprintf formatting issues - CVE-2005-3962
        6663288 Upgrade to CGI.pm 3.33
        REGEXP0 - fix for UTF-8 recoding in regexps - CVE-2007-5116
  Built under solaris
  Compiled at Jul 31 2008 10:45:31
  @INC:
    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int
    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib
    /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/i86pc-solaris-64int
    /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4
    /usr/perl5/site_perl
    /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/i86pc-solaris-64int
    /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4
    /usr/perl5/vendor_perl
    .
```

Comment: Ugh, line endings are all messed up :|

Comment: Fozi brings up a good point; is the script itself written using utf8?  If so, you definately need `use UTF8`.

Comment: I upgraded to 5.10 on the solaris box and it works fine now.

Comment: Do we get to see the script or the input or the environment? It's very hard to give accurate answers when you hide all the important information from us. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use utf8; or [use encoding](http://perldoc.perl.org/encoding.html) "whatever";.

Answer (score 0):

The perls (lowercase perl, I'm talking about the executable here, Perl fans ;) ) could be compiled differently.  If you could show us the `perl -V` from each of them, we might be able to give you a better answer.

Update:

Well, it looks like a diff shows that the only real difference is the compile date from the perl side of things.  If so, the next thing I'd check are the libraries that you are using are the same versions (look for `$VERSION = X.X.X` or `$VERSION = X.XXX_XXX` or something like that.)

If the libraries you are using are the same, it might be the shell itself; it might be configured to interpret the output using different locales.  Try doing a

```
perl myscript.pl > out.txt
```

on the solaris box and seeing if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any differences in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding used by your terminals.